# How to fit a website on windows mobile web browser through code + c#

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

hey in my application i use web browser component on a windows form and display any website that user types in say "google.com"

but that website does not fit in properly with the screen size

how can i do that through code?

i cant find any property of windows mobile...

can somebody help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well friends i got the answer
you r not required to change the display size

Windows mobile automatically did my work.It displayed the website properly..I think there was some network problem so web page cldn't display properly(think so)

God Knows y earlier it didn't worked!!!!!1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is discussed in Microsoft Knowledge Base article 975281:

FIX: You cannot scroll through a Web page or visit a link by using a .NET Compact Framework 3.5-based application that hosts a WebBrowser control in Windows Mobile 6.1.4 or in Windows Mobile 6.5

The symptoms section says:

Additionally, in Windows Mobile 6.5, the horizontal and vertical scroll bars do not appear.

A supported hotfix is available from Microsoft to resolve these problems. The hotfix is a whole new build of the .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

So this is not a problem with the your code or with the specific device.

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f38afd20-dd8b-481e-813c-ed91db1df6c8/scrollbars-missing-on-webbrowser-control-net-v20-c-windows-mobile-65-no-way-to-scroll?forum=netfxcompact][1]